# This part of my code (which is supposed to remove Python 2-style comments from other python scripts) doesn't do anything. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comments

This is only 30 lines long, so I'll post the whole thing. This entire script is supposed to take another .py file and rewrite it so that it's entirely on one line. A problem I ran into is that if the script has any comments at all, it will comment out every other "line." The part that doesn't work is commented with # ****THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK**** What that part is supposed to do is delete the # character and everything after it on that line, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def make_one_line(f):
    # reads the file, then adds each line to a list
    # then adds that line to 'final'
    one_line = ''
    text_body = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    lines = text_body.splitlines()
    lines.reverse() # this is done because pop() starts at the back
    # ****THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK****
    for line in lines:
        line.split("#")
    # ****THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK****
    while lines != []:
        next_one = lines.pop()
        one_line += next_one
        one_line += ';'
    return one_line


print "This will rewrite the file, press CTRL-C to cancel."
raw_input('Press any key (but CTRL-C) to continue.')

current_file = open(input_file, 'r+')
final = make_one_line(current_file)
current_file.truncate()
current_file.seek(0) # if this isn't here, you get an error on Windows
current_file.write(final)
```

Comment: I think what you meant is `line = ''.join(line.split('#'))` I'm not sure though, try it out.

Answer (score 2):

str.split is a function that returns the split elements.  It does not modify its arguments, as strings are immutable.  You also can't write to the list you're iterating over with a for loop.  Instead consider:

```
uncommented_lines = []
for line in lines:
    uncommented_lines.append(line.split('#')[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Steve's answer as he pointed out strings are immutable. Also is there any reason to use `read()`, `splitlines()`, `reverse()` and `pop()`? Wouldn't this work:

```
def make_one_line(f):
    uncommented_lines = (line.rstrip('\n').split('#')[0] for line in f) 
    return ';'.join(uncommented_lines)
```

Comment: Your answer is definitely better than mine for the best way to solve this problem, but feels to me like giving a man a fish.  While that's a solid way to solve this problem, what's wrong with his code is not that it's not idiomatic, but that it's not quite grasping how the language works.

Comment: Well...I'm not very good at Python. I don't even know what your code does.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this, and it removes the comments, but doesn't cover the whole file. There's still parts that are on multiple lines.

Comment: @andrew The first line is a generator expression `uncommmented_lines = ( ... )`, generators allow you to construct an object that you can iterate over while deferring the actual execution. You could use a list comprehension `[ ... ]` but this would have read through the whole file and store it in memory. With the generator the file doesn't get read until the second line `';'.join()'`. Suggest reading up about generators and comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want with a lot less code and more efficiently:

```
import fileinput

print ';'.join(line.strip('\n ').split('#')[0] for line in fileinput.input())
```

To test put this code in `make_one_line.py` and then do:

```
python make_one_line.py other.py
```